# Set all select elements in a table to the same width as the widest one in its column

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngtable

As a design requirement, I need to make sure that all of the select elements in a given column are the same width, using the widest select in that column to set them by.

Example:

[image]

The widths should only match those others from the same column, and not be matched to the widest `<select>` in the entire table.

I've concocted a function which seems like it should work (see below), but it's executing *before* the page data reloads, no matter where I stick it.

The call to the function is currently at the end of the `getData` function in `ngTableParams`.

The function:

```
$scope.resizeInputs = function(table, inputType) {
    var cols = [],
        rows = table+" tbody tr";

    angular.forEach($(rows), function(element, key, obj) {
        $(element).find('td').each(function(i, el) {
            var thisInput = $(el).find(inputType),
                currentWidth = cols[i] == null ? null : cols[i],
                maxWidth = Math.max(currentWidth, $(thisInput).width());

            if (thisInput.length > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
                cols[i] = maxWidth;
            }
        });
    });

    $.each(cols, function(index, el) {
        if (el != undefined) {
            var x = index + 1;
            $(rows).children('td:nth-child('+x+')').find(inputType).width(el);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:** getData function:

```
$scope.searchTable = function(){
    $scope.doSelectFunctions = true;
    $scope.copySendDate = null;
    var today = new Date();
    todayStr = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();
    searchCriteria = {
//                startDate: toStartTimeStamp(todayStr),
            startDate: toStartTimeStamp("11/01/2014"),
            endDate: toEndTimeStamp(todayStr)
    };

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        count: 100,            // Default results per page, down from 1000!
        sorting: {
            pending: 'desc',
            campaignId: 'desc',
            }
        },{
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // ajax request to api
            $timeout(function() {
                Report.search(searchCriteria, function(data) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function(v,k) {
                        $scope.doCampaignInfo(v);

                        if (pageData.bulkProfileData.length == 0) {
                            pageData.bulkProfileData.push({ioOfferId:v.ioOfferId, profileId:v.profileId});
                        }
                        else if (v.ioOfferId != null && v.profileId != null) {
                            var stop = pageData.bulkProfileData.length,
                                ioOfferIdFound = false,
                                profileIdFound = false;

                            for (var i = 0; i< stop; i++) {
                                if (pageData.bulkProfileData[i].ioOfferId == v.ioOfferId) {
                                    ioOfferIdFound = true;
                                }
                                if (pageData.bulkProfileData[i].profileId == v.profileId) {
                                    profileIdFound = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!ioOfferIdFound || !profileIdFound) {
                                pageData.bulkProfileData.push({ioOfferId:v.ioOfferId, profileId:v.profileId})
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $scope.campaignData = data;
                    $scope.doProfileAssetStats($scope.campaignData);                        
                    $scope.searchDone = true;
                    $scope.dataLoading  = false;

                    // Sort the data
                    var orderedData = params.sorting ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;

                    // Filter the data
                    orderedData = $filter('campaignStatusFilter')(orderedData, $scope.campaignStatusForFilter);
                    orderedData = $filter('filter')(orderedData, $scope.tblSearch);

                    // Update table params
                    params.total(orderedData.length);

                    // Slice off the data for the current page
                    $scope.campaignData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                    // Set the lastPage
                    $scope.lastPage = Math.ceil($scope.tableParams.total() / $scope.tableParams.count());

                    // Resize all the select elements
                    $scope.resizeInputs('#search-results', 'select');

                    // Do the stuff
                    $defer.resolve($scope.campaignData);
                });
            }, 50);
        }
    });
};
```

If I could instead use a pure Angular solution, I'd much prefer that.  Is there a way to bind the select elements in each column so that they share the same width?  That would be best, if possible, since the widths of the `<select>`s will change when a different value is selected!

Thanks!

Comment: could you show your getData function?

Comment: @wrschneider99 Updated to include getData function.

Comment: why u not applying `resizeInputs` on data resolving etc on  ` $defer.resolve($scope.campaignData).then(function(){ resizeInputs})`? it will right after data binding to view

Comment: @KostiaMololkin When I try that, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".  If I put `$defer.promise.then(resizeInputs(...))` before the resolve, I get no error but obviously it doesn't run when it should. I'm totally new to Angular, so I don't quite get all this promise then defer stuff...

Comment: right i mistaken it must be `$defer.promise.then(resizeInputs(...))`,so that's mean it's no right place,so u can try make it more late by using timer inside  `then` ,not outside - it must work, i will make plunk for example a little bit later

Comment: You could also try wrapping the resizeInputs in another timeout to give the DOM generated by the table a chance to render first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this can be done with a simple CSS directive.

```
select {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

If not, then maybe this version of your own code :

```
$scope.resizeInputs = function(table, inputType) {
    var cols = [],
        rows = table + " tbody tr";
    $(rows).each(function(i, tr) {
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            cols[i] = Math.max(cols[i] || 0, $(td).find(inputType).width() || 0);
        });
    }).each(function(i, tr) {
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            $(td).find(inputType).width(cols[i]);
        });
    });
}
```

Seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/Lenkhvvp/

**Edit ...**

To trigger the function from the digest cycle, write it as follows :

```
function resizeInputs(table, inputType) {
    var cols = [],
        rows = table + " tbody tr";
    $(rows).each(function(i, tr) {
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            cols[i] = Math.max(cols[i] || 0, $(td).find(inputType).width() || 0);
        });
    }).each(function(i, tr) {
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            $(td).find(inputType).width(cols[i]);
        });
    });
}
```

and establish a `$watch` :

```
$rootScope.$watch(resizeInputs.bind(null, '#myTable', 'select'));
```

**Edit 2 ...**

You should be able to chop the function down the middle, into a "watcher" half and a "resizer" half.

As I understand it, the watcher will always run once per digest but the resizer can be made to run once per observed change by returning the "value being watched" from the watcher. But, unlike the example in the angular documentation, our "value being watched" is an array - namely `cols`. We could simply return `cols` but it will be kinder to return `cols.join()`, which will be more easily compared with its previous value.

Again as I understand it, comparison of the returned value is performed automatically by angular, and a manual `oldValue !== newValue` comparison is only necessary to suppress undesirable effects on initialization. However, there's no harm in doing the comparison if you can be bothered to code it.

Putting all that together, I arrive at the following :

```
function watcher(table, inputType) {
    var cols = [],
        rows = table + " tbody tr";
    $(rows).each(function(i, tr) {
        $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            cols[i] = Math.max(cols[i] || 0, $(td).find(inputType).width() || 0);
        });
    });
    return cols.join();
}
function resizer(table, inputType, oldValue, newValue) {
    if(newValue !== oldValue) {
        var cols = newValue.split(','),
            rows = table + " tbody tr";
        $(rows).each(function(i, tr) {
            $(tr).find('td').each(function(i, td) {
                $(td).find(inputType).width(cols[i]);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Now, we can give the  "$watch" statement its two parameters, each being a function with bound in values.

```
$rootScope.$watch(
    watcher.bind(null, '#search-results', 'select'), 
    resizer.bind(null, '#search-results', 'select')
);
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. I tried using every CSS trick I could think of, but unless I specify a width somewhere, all the select elements just shrink down to about 100px or so.

Comment: The columns need to expand and contract, depending on the size of the select elements.

Comment: How about ... let the table render, then (in a window.onload handler) set column widths in concrete from javascript. I've never tried it but that should give the CSS `width:100%` directive something to bite on.

Comment: That's more or less what my function is supposed to do... sorta.  I may just need to scrap this and try another route altogether, but you have given me some good ideas. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe a slightly different version of your own code - see above.

Comment: The code I have works perfectly; the issue is that it's not executing when it's supposed to.  If I link my function to a button, it works great.  I need it to automagically run when the data or table are changed.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda lost sight of that. I wonder if you need to establish a [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)?

Comment: I've added a suggestion to the answer, involving `$watch` - give it a try.

Comment: It's written using a function as a "watchExpression" and no "listener". AFAIK, this is allowed. It's a cheap way of making something happen once per digest.

Comment: I had to add `$rootScope` to the function parameters, but now I'm getting "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: Try moving `resizeInputs` into the `$watch()` as an anonymous function. And avoid the need for `.bind()` by hard-coding your table id and 'select' inside the function.

Comment: My bad!  I didn't change the function from `$scope.resizeInputs()` to `function resizeInputs()`. That's why the bind() method wasn't working initially.  This, and your previous suggestions both work now!  There's just one last issue... The function is executing about 7 times each time anything is changed.  How can I add newvalue and oldvalue into the equation so that it only runs when changed? I'm currently using the `$rootScope.$watch(resizeInputs.bind(null, '#search-results', 'select'));` solution.

Comment: I'm into unknown territory here, so please bear with me. See Edit 2, which is my best shot.

Comment: I really really can't thank you enough for all your help!  I appreciate your time and effort!!

Comment: No worries Don'lo. Good luck with it.